# Github actions failing on installation of dependencies

Tags: github-actions

Github actions throwing error:

> Run composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts
> --no-progress --prefer-dist   composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist   shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Error: The operation was canceled.

Please see configuration and image below:

Laravel.yml file

```yaml
name: Laravel
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
      - features/**
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Service container Postgresql postgresql
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image (also with version)
        image: postgres:latest
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB:  db_test_laravel
        ## map the "external" 55432 port with the "internal" 5432
        ports:
          - 55432:5432
        # Set health checks to wait until postgresql database has started (it takes some seconds to start)
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    strategy:
      matrix:
        operating-system: [ubuntu-latest]
        php-versions: [ '8.0','7.4' ]
        dependency-stability: [ prefer-stable ]

    name: P${{ matrix.php-versions }} - L${{ matrix.laravel }} - ${{ matrix.dependency-stability }} - ${{ matrix.operating-system}}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '15.x'
    - name: Cache node_modules directory
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: node_modules-cache
      with:
        path: node_modules
        key: ${{ runner.OS }}-build-${{ hashFiles('**/package.json') }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
    - name: Install NPM packages
      if: steps.node_modules-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: npm ci
    - name: Build frontend
      run: npm run development
    - name: Install PHP versions
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: ${{ matrix.php-versions }}
    - name: Get Composer Cache Directory 2
      id: composer-cache
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=dir::$(composer config cache-files-dir)"
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: actions-cache
      with:
        path: ${{ steps.composer-cache.outputs.dir }}
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-composer-
    - name: Cache PHP dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: vendor-cache
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.OS }}-build-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      if: steps.vendor-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist

    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Run Migrations
      # Set environment
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
        DB_DATABASE: db_test_laravel
        DB_PORT: 55432
        DB_USERNAME: postgres
        DB_PASSWORD: postgres

      run: php artisan migrate

    - name: Show dir
      run: pwd
    - name: PHP Version
      run: php --version

    # Code quality
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      # Set environment
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
        DB_DATABASE: db_test_laravel
        DB_PORT: 55432
        DB_USERNAME: postgres
        DB_PASSWORD: postgres

      run: vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox
```

[Action summary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDspC.png)

Composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by doing the following:

Changed the version to `php-versions: [ '8.0' ]`

Github actions run successfully.